# How to pass comma separated values to stored procedure in MySql?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure like

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`test`@`%` PROCEDURE  `test`.`get_details`(
    in p_istudid int,
    in p_icourseid int,
    in p_branchid varchar(20)
    )
    BEGIN
    select ...
    ...
    and branch.id in(p_branchid);
    END
```

I want to pass comma separated values to 3rd parameter, how to pass that values?
I tried like -

```
 call get_details(10,11,'20,30');
```

but is only showing records have branch id 20, not 30.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [prepare statement to pass comma-separated values to stored procedure parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25508686/prepare-statement-to-pass-comma-separated-values-to-stored-procedure-parameter)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL variable format for a "NOT IN" list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957643/mysql-variable-format-for-a-not-in-list-of-values)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass comma separated values in procedures however you need to use prepared statement to use it, since the values you pass should be concatenated in the query.

```
delimiter //
   CREATE DEFINER=`test`@`%` PROCEDURE  `test`.`get_details`(
    in p_istudid int,
    in p_icourseid int,
    in p_branchid varchar(20)
    )
    BEGIN
    set @qry = concat('select .... and branch.id in (\'',p_branchid,'\')');
    prepare stmp from @qry;
    execute stmp ;
    deallocate prepare stmp;
    END;//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: And note that you sacrifice protection against "SQL Injection".